# How to migrate from APT-managed `snapd` to snap-based `snapd`

Tags: apt, snap

In order to be able to try out some new features of `snapd` that are only available on the edge channel, it's usually advised to use `snap refresh --edge snapd`, however on Ubuntu classic (as opposed to Core) `snapd` is managed by APT, not by itself.

How can I safely move to a snap for `snapd`?

<sup><sub>This question is posted for reference, I'll also post the answer I got out-of-band :-)</sub></sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To safely move to snap-based `snapd`, simply use `sudo snap install snapd`. The APT-managed `snapd` will automatically do the right thing and re-exec into the snap-managed `snapd`.

However, do **not** remove the .deb package from your system, as it is the owner of the systemd service file starting up `snapd`.